# Google Analytics tracking Issues

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I had been tracking my domain at - http://foamymedia.com - perfectly fine, then i set up a subdomain - http://apps.foamymedia.com and added the same code to the subdomain.

The subdomain tracking is working perfectly, however it now seems my main site traffic is not being picked up at all.

I have tried various times to add the code to the head and footer, manually and using wordpress plugins but with no success.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think i had a custom filter which was blocking traffic being reported!